# iTextSharp - Keeping parts of a page together

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to figure out how to group a variety of small items together, and make sure they appear on the same page.  For example if I had an image and some text, I'd like them to show up on a new page if there was not enough room.

I see there are a few options like "KeepTogether" and SplitLate, but they seem to refer to a single item as opposed to applying the effect to multiple items together.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I see, I didn't realize elements could be added into the paragraph.  So I can create a paragraph and then add images, lists, etc to it and it will keep together!